# Is an iTunes card country-specific?

Tags: itunes

If I buy a iTunes card in Europe, Holland, could I (or anyone who has the key) use it in Australia?

Answer (score 3):

[iTunes Gift Cards](http://store.apple.com/us/browse/home/giftcards/itunes/gallery) will only work in the same country they were bought in.

> iTunes Gift Cards are not available in Luxembourg, Portugal, or Greece. **Gift recipient must have or open an iTunes Store account in the same country as purchaser to redeem gift.** The iTunes Store is available only to persons age 13 or older in the U.S. and many other countries; see http://www.apple.com/support/itunes/ww for a list of countries. Requires iTunes 6.0 or later (7.0 or later for video), compatible hardware and software, and Internet access (fees may apply). Terms apply. See http://www.apple.com/itunes/store for more information.

Of course, if you buy a card for yourself, you’re both the *purchaser* and the *recipient*. **So only buy iTunes Gift Cards in countries where you have an iTunes Store account.**

Answer (score 3):

I once had the same thing. My girlfriend bought me a iTunes Gift Card in The Netherlands, but since we live in Belgium, I couldn't use it. So I contacted Apple and the responded:

> Michiel, unfortunately, ***gift cards and gift certificates are
>   redeemable only on the iTunes Store for the country for which they
>   were purchased***. International gift exchanges are not allowed.
>
> I know that is disappointing, and I do apologize for the
>   inconvenience, but perhaps your friend would like to give the card to
>   someone who lives in The Netherlands, or use it herself.
>
> Please do not hesitate to let me know if you have any further
>   questions, Michiel, and I will gladly assist you further. Have an
>   awesome day and thanks for being a part of our iTunes family.
>
> Sincerely,
>
> Ms Gerri
>   iTunes Store Customer Support
>   http://www.apple.com/support/itunes/ww/

Answer (score 0):

Well I changed my iTunes Store account and went from the Greek to the German. So, now I am buying from Germany iTunes cards and purchase items from the German App Store.