# How do I redeem an App Gift from a different App Store? "This code is only valid for customers of the ___ Store."

Tags: ios

My friend has sent me a gift app from the Singapore App Store whilst I'm on the Australian App store.

I encounter the following:
"This code is only valid for customers of the Singapore Store."

How do I redeem this?

Answer (score 3):

Related to [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46938/is-an-itunes-card-country-specific) question.

And the answer is, gift cards and gift certificates are redeemable only on the iTunes Store for the country for which they were purchased.

Answer (score 1):

You can register an iTunes account that uses Singapore App Store, and download from there.